# Alternative to OSGi?

Tags: osgi, firmware, software-update

I need to implement a remote management system that does the following tasks on remote devices-
1) Install Software,Firmware.
2) Install Upgrades of the Software,Firmware.
3) Monitor the state of the installed software,Firmware.

OSGi can be one of the framework to achieve this, but it only supports bundles written in Java(implementations for C/C++ are available but they are not matured). I was wondering if there are any other alternatives that can manage software written in any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this question come up from time to time, but I don't think there is, and I doubt there will be,especially on mobile devices. Getting an API that 'feels good' regardless of language is pretty much impossible, and you need to interface with how a particular platform handles its updates. Provisioning OSGi components is just fundamentally different than updating an iOS app.

Then again, I'd love to be proven wrong on this one;-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could have a look on MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework). Its for dotNet development and similar to OSGi. But I am more familar to OSGi as to MEF so I cannot tell the differences. I only heard from a C# pro that they have MEF instead of OSGi ^^